# Javascript array value compare

Tags: javascript

I am checking each checkbox status (2 elements in total).

```
var checked = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox').forEach(function(e,i){
 checked.push(e.checked)
})
```

Now checked value could be

```
(2) [true, true]
```

or

```
(2) [true, false]
```

or

```
(2) [false, true]
```

or

```
(2) [false, false]
```

I am now checking it with a little bit manual way

```
if(checked[0] && check[1]) { ... }
```

If I have more elements, I have to add them manually like

```
 if(checked[0] && check[1] && check[2]) { ... }
```

I am seeking a better way to polish my code, so I don't need to manually add array values to compare. Thanks

Comment: You want to check if all are true or not?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to check if all true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to do that like this

```js
const pass = [true, true, true]
const passNot = [true, false, true]

const reducer = (isPassing, value) => {
  if (value === false) return false
  else return isPassing
}

console.log('yay', pass.reduce(reducer, true))
console.log('nay', passNot.reduce(reducer, true))
```

Comment: This method supports IE and most of mobile browsers! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `every` and `Array.from`

```
var checked = [];
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
var allChecked = Array.from( allCheckboxes ).every( s => s.checked )
```

Comment: ah! yes! `every` Thank you very much

Comment: just checked  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from IE doesnt support `from` Is there a way to support IE and some mobile browsers ? Thanks

Comment: @olo You can use every's pollyfil https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to combine an array of values into a single one, thats what the `reduce` method does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
    let result = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')
    .map( box => box.checked ) // get an array of boolean
    .reduce ( (bool, res) => return bool && res /*all checkboxes must be checked */, true /* initial value */ );
```